# Xamarin - Refresh list after PopAsync()

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am writing an application using Xamarin-forms. When I navigate away from my page which edits a list, using `popAsync()` , I want to refresh a list on the previous page so that my changes are shown.

my `PopulateMachineSelectionList()` adds my `machine` objects to the list.

This is what I've tried so far

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {

        PopulateMachineSelectionList();
        base.OnAppearing();
    }


    async void PopulateMachineSelectionList()
    { 
        loadedMachines = await machineSync.GetMachines();
        if (loadedMachines.Count() != 0)
        {
            machineSelectionList.Clear();

            foreach (Machine mach in loadedMachines)
            { //I have an archive boolean that determines whether or not machines should be shown
                if (!mach.archived)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Adding: " + mach.name + " to the list template");
                    machineSelectionList.Add(new ListTemplate(null, mach.name, true, true));
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Refresh List");
            machineList.ItemsSource = machineSelectionList;

        }
        machineList.SelectedItem = null;

    }
```

Comment: Is machineList ObservableCollection?

Comment: I'd like to help, but there's few information about your scenario. Please, edit your question and add more data. Contextualize us about the whole thing that you're having problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like, the following code:

```
machineList.ItemsSource.Clear(); 
machineList.ItemsSource.Add(machineSelectionList);
```

Possibly this will trigger, the `propertychanged` Event.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a page A (with the ListView) and a page B (that edit the list binded to ListView) I think you can pass pageAViewModel (that should have the "list") to pageB, and modify it. You should have your changes automatically updated to PageA (if you use ObservableCollection and INPC).

Otherwise you could use MessagingCenter. Send a Message from B to A before the Pop and on "Subscribe" set your ItemsSource again

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call `machineList.ItemsSource =` from the Main Thread.

It also may help to nullify the original ItemSource and assign the new ItemSource to a new List.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{

    PopulateMachineSelectionList();
    base.OnAppearing();
}


async void PopulateMachineSelectionList()
{ 
    loadedMachines = await machineSync.GetMachines();
    if (loadedMachines.Count() != 0)
    {
        machineSelectionList.Clear();

        foreach (Machine mach in loadedMachines)
        { //I have an archive boolean that determines whether or not machines should be shown
            if (!mach.archived)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding: " + mach.name + " to the list template");
                machineSelectionList.Add(new ListTemplate(null, mach.name, true, true));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Refresh List");
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            machineList.ItemsSource = null;
            machineList.ItemsSource = new List(machineSelectionList);
        });

    }
    machineList.SelectedItem = null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the first page :

```
NavigatedTo += async (s, e) => { await Refresh(); };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).